# Why does my expo app crash after build apk

Tags: android, react-native, crash, expo, logcat

**the app doesn't open
after I update the code and add:
Admob +
i18n-js Localization.
i think its Localization but i do it right is there any promotion for it in-app JSON like wifi or something like that
my app.json**

```
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "vat 15%",
    "description": "Fastest tax Added Calculator 15%",
    "slug": "vatApp",
    "platforms": [
      "ios",
      "android",
      "web"
    ],
    "version": "1.2.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/icon.png",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "updates": {
      "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*"
    ],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true,
      "config": {
        "googleMobileAdsAppId": "ca-app-pub-ideletetThis"
      }
    },
    "android": {
      "package": "com.ideletetThis.ideletetThis",
      "versionCode": 2,
      "config": {
        "googleMobileAdsAppId": "ca-app-pub-i delete"
      }
    },
    "sdkVersion": "38.0.0"
  }
}
```

**log cat Error on apk**

```
 Process: com.myappname.ideletetThis, PID: 23538
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAdsInitProvider: java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
    
    ******************************************************************************
    * Invalid application ID. Follow instructions here: https:// goo . gl/fQ2neu to *
    * find your app ID.                                                          *
    ******************************************************************************
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved after adding Admob android key in **JSON file**

```
 "android": {
      "package":"com.stackoverflow.vatApp",
      "versionCode": 2,
      "config": {
        "googleMobileAdsAppId":"ca-app-pub-349893000004~000000"
      }
```

Comment: I am having the same issue you had this in the initial code right?
`"config": {
        "googleMobileAdsAppId":"ca-app-pub-349893000004~000000"
      }` how did you resolve your issue please help

Answer (score -1):

Add below meta data in Manifest.xml

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
    android:value=**appID**/>
```

Comment: expo use json entstad xml